# Regex whitelisted url lets blocked urls through on the same line in message

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, regexp-replace

So I have a regex expression which blocks URLs in a message, but I want to whitelist the site's URL.

currently it works with any prefix like HTTP://www.example.com and with [www.example.com/support/how-do-i-setup-this](http://www.example.com/support/how-do-i-setup-this) but if I put another URL behind this then it gets through the filter which I don't want (only if I put the new URL on a new line it gets blocked as required)

"go to http://example.com/support/how-do-i www.badurl.com" this doesn't block the badurl which I want to happen

also this string results in both being blocked "www.badurl.comexample.com" but ideally I would like to whitelist the example.com URL here too

```
[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,24}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?(?<!\bexample.com(/.*)?)
```

Current python function code

```
import re

def link_remover(message):
   #remove any links that aren't in whitelist
   message = re.sub(r"[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,24}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?(?<!\bexample.com)", "[URL Removed]", message)
   return message
```

so I'm just wondering how to edit it to fix those two examples which fail?

I appreciate any responses or pointing me in the right direction :)

Comment: You didn't mention the language where the regex is used, I assume Python looking at the name etc. Or maybe not, as it doesn't even work in Python. But regardless, this seems like a much better job for regular text processing functions or multiple regexes.

Comment: Also, domains can have more than 4 characters, e.g. `.tourism`.

Comment: hi, currently testing it in python, I added my python function to the question, but it will be deployed in ruby on rails for a website backend so just wondering about the regex part. I'm still new to regex only discovered it earlier today lol, but just wondering if I would have 2 regexes to achieve this wouldn't the first block all links and then the second wouldn't be able to whitelist it? or if the first whitelists it then the second would block it anyway? that's why I figured having it in one would work. ah also appreciate the long tld mention, I didn't notice that just increased it to 24

Comment: URL's notoriously need boundaries around them to stop the **_bleed_** of unintended adjacent text matching, and in your case, throwing off a URL exclusion. What boundaries have you set in your regex ? Typical boundary pairs include `(?<!\S)(?!\S)`, `\b\b`, `^$` etc...

Comment: So, firstly, testing a regex in Python just to later deploy in Ruby is pointless as different languages use different regex engines/implementations. Python may have something Ruby doesn't and vice versa. Secondly, I don't know where your logic comes from. You, as programmer, can build whatever conditions yyou want with as many whitelist/blacklist regexes as you want. It's just a matter of adding more conditions, function returns etc.

Comment: got it, I guess the boundary could be a space at the end of it. but ideally if it spots another URL inside a whitelisted URL it should block that e.g. "https://www.example.com/support/scamsite.com more message here"

Comment: No regex will handle a nested URL. I'll give you a URL regex showing how to do exclusions.

Comment: Ok so do you want to _match_ bad whitelisted URL's and remove them ?

Comment: yeah, so I want to match all URLs detected using that regex code to remove them as it seems to do a good job, just want to whitelist the sites domain to not be matched and removed "example.com" (and variations with www/http(s) or with a page linked at the end of it)

Comment: Ok so in your re.sub, the regex says match if it doesn't find `(?<!\bexample.com)` and replace with `Removed` So all ones _without_ this url will be removed. Is that what you want ? Or is what you mean was with it, then remove it, like `(?<=\bexample.com)`

Comment: In the end you have to match both the bad and the good UTL's. If it is a bad url, replace with `remove`. If it's good, then don't replace it. This logic requires a callback. It's easy to do, just need to see if it is a whitelist style.

Comment: yes that's what I want to happen, just want to figure out those 2 instances where I have a whitelisted URL and another URL on the same line "example.com/support and badurl.com " then it doesn't match either of them when I want it to still match the non whitelisted URL. or when a whitelisted URL is next to another URL it blocks both but ideally I want it to let the whitelisted one through "badurl.comexample.com" although this second example isn't important just mainly the first one

Comment: Ok, the `example.com` was a whitelist one. Realize that a whitelisted must contain _all_ the ones you want to let through. There is just the good, everything else is bad. Alyernatively, only the _bad_ are searched for, everything else gets through. Can't really have it both ways.

Comment: I have a robust url regex. One of the things I can do is to splice a blacklist into it. This is a fragment. `(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*`  `< (?<!bad)(?=\.com) >` `(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,}))` there are boundaries and other parts. Let me know how you want to do this. Or it could match the bad `< (?<=bad)(?=\.com) >`

Comment: Or can go upstream and put a list of bad urls `(?=[^\s]*?(?:bad1|bad2|bad3|bad4)\.com)`

Comment: that would be great, I just want to block all URLs apart from this one "example.com" and any variations of it like "https://example.com" "www.example.com/support" all of those I want to not be matched so it stays untouched when I replace the rest

Comment: Ok, I posted something. Will post the full Python code tomorrow sometime.

Comment: Ok, added updated regex method and Python code sample. This works fairly good. It's not perfect without boundaries though, but due to the regex detail, free form should be adequate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Final Update:***
Added a negative lookbehind boundary that starts every check for a whitelist item.
Example:  `(?<=(?<![-a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9])example\.com)`
This class ensures that only an optional *Subdomain* can come before it.
As the only optional parts of the regex allow only a dot or forward slash.
Therefore no bleed of letters can be adjacent to it, for example *`wrongexample.com`* .

This is an example where the whitelist items are optionally matched.
Every url is matched. The whitelist check is strategically placed right after the domain
is matched. Therefore the match will encompass any trailing optional ports or directories.

A lambda callback is all that's needed to check if *any* of the whitelist urls matched.
If so, just write them back unchanged.
If none matched then write back the *Removed* string.

***Modified logic:***
Changed to only need one capture group.
The *group* is used as a flag.

If the group is *None*, no whitelist item was found for the match.
Returns *`return {Empty}`* in the callback and overwrites the bad url.

Otherwise a whitelist item was found. The match is return unchanged.
*`return m.group(0)`*.

Notes:
All url's are matched.  Single capture group.  Unlimited number of whitelist items.
Follow the template below to add the whitelist items.

```
(?!mailto:)(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)?(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?:(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,}))((?<=(?<![-a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9])example\.com)|(?<=(?<![-a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9])example1\.com)|(?<=(?<![-a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9])example2\.com))?))|localhost)(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/[^\s]*)?
```

https://regex101.com/r/rCBd0P/1

***Python Code Sample:***

```
import re
 
def ConvertURL_func(input_text):
  #
  def repl(m):
    if m.group(1) == None: return "{Removed}"
    return m.group(0)
  #
  input_text = re.sub(r"(?!mailto:)(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)?(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?:(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,}))((?<=(?<![-a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9])example\.com)|(?<=(?<![-a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9])example1\.com)|(?<=(?<![-a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9])example2\.com))?))|localhost)(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/[^\s]*)?",repl,input_text)
  return input_text

# input URL strings example:
input_text = '''
bad.com
www.example.com
example.com
www.badurl.com www.badurlexample2.com
www.badurl.com example1.com
https://www.example2.com
'''

input_text = ConvertURL_func(input_text)
print(input_text)
```

Outout:

```
>>> print(input_text)

{Removed}
www.example.com
example.com
{Removed} {Removed}
{Removed} example1.com
https://www.example2.com

>>>
```

***Regex expanded:***

```
 (?! mailto: )
 (?:
    (?: https? | ftp )
    :\/\/
 )?
 (?:
    \S+ 
    (?: : \S* )?
    @
 )?
 (?:
    (?:
       (?:
          [1-9] \d? 
        | 1 \d\d 
        | 2 [01] \d 
        | 22 [0-3] 
       )
       (?:
          \.
          (?: 1? \d{1,2} | 2 [0-4] \d | 25 [0-5] )
       ){2}
       (?:
          \.
          (?:
             [1-9] \d? 
           | 1 \d\d 
           | 2 [0-4] \d 
           | 25 [0-4] 
          )
       )
     | 
       (?:
          (?:
             (?: [a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+ -? )*
             [a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+ 
          )
          (?:
             \.
             (?: [a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+ -? )*
             [a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+ 
          )*
          (?:
             \.
             (?: [a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,} )
          )
          (                           # (1 start)
             # Start Whitelist
             
             (?<=
                (?<! [-a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9] )
                example\.com
             )
           | (?<=
                (?<! [-a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9] )
                example1\.com
             )
           | (?<=
                (?<! [-a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9] )
                example2\.com
             )
             
             # Add more whitelist items
          )?                          # (1 end)
       )
    )
  | localhost
 )
 (?: : \d{2,5} )?
 (?: \/ [^\s]* )?
```

Comment: thanks for this answer! The updated solution words perfectly for me and works with directories too

Comment: One final change. Added boundary clause at the beginning of each whitelist entry. It's explained in the post. It basically will not now match extended names like _`wrongexample.com`_. Otherwise it was susceptible to matching that.